# How to hide verification message window of adding new toolbar

Tags: c#, windows, toolbar, deskband

I am trying in C# to add a new toolbar into my task bar, as you can see above:
[image]

Now, anytime I want to show this icon (by code) I get this message:

[image]

My question is - how to hide this message window ? 
Which means, the toolbar will be added automatically without this Yes/No window.
When I try to show the icon manually, like here:
[image]

the message window is not shown up.
I am using DeskBand by C#.

I investigate as long as I could and didn't find any satisfied answer.

Thanks,